# Where should I connect the E wire on my Nest Thermostat?

Tags: thermostat, nest

I am trying to install a Nest thermostat and I have (R, O/B, Y, G, E, W2, C) wires in my old thermostat, but the Nest only has (Y, C, W, G, R, *OB). So where do I connect the E wire if there isn’t a terminal for it?

Comment: What make and model is your air handler/furnace, and can you post photos of the wiring at it please?

Comment: I believe there are Nest thermostats such as the Nest E that do not support heat pumps with auxiliary/emergency heat.  Based on the wiring you have, it seems like you have a heat pump.

Answer (score 0):

E is likely (no guarantee in the wonderful world of thermostats) for Emergency Heat. That is typically a resistance heat supplement to a heat pump when the outside temperature is too cold for the heat pump to work properly. If you don't connect E then it may mean you will never get emergency heat when it is actually needed. Or it may have no effect at all if the heat pump manages emergency heat on its own. It is also possible that the E wire isn't even connected at the heat pump or is combined with another wire at the heat pump.

For more details, we'd need (a) make/model of HVAC system (heat pump assumed but could be anything) and (b) a picture showing how the wires and connect to the HVAC system.